# creating 2d array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie at js and trying to create a 2D array but when I run the code I get in the console
`Array(10) [ <10 empty slots> ]`  even though I filled the array with values.
This is my js and HTML:

```js
function Make2Darray(cols, rows) {
  let arr = new Array(cols);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(rows);
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = floor(random(2));
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
let grid;
grid = Make2Darray(10, 10);
console.log(grid);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Game of Life</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="gol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Typo, its `length` not `lenght`

Comment: At line 3 in the javascript portion, it should be `arr.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You made 2 mistakes : one the 3rd line, this is not `arr.length` that you want but `cols`
Then, floor and random are parts of the Math lib provided by JS, so use it like this:

```
arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

Comment: OP means Math.random()*2. Math.random takes 0 arguments. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Yep, i just copied his code and didn't noticed this, i edited

Comment: Are you sure `floor` and `random` are not provided by p5.js? Because there are no errors in the snippet...

Comment: GJ i didn't see P5 include

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `floor(random(2))` part, but you can create 2D array as below:

```js
function Make2Darray(rows, cols) {
  let arr = []
 
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random()) // You can change the value in this part
    }
  }
 
  return arr
}

let grid = Make2Darray(10, 10)
console.log(grid)
```